# « Une tête de plus que » et « la tête de plus que »

Tags: vocabulaire, articles, france, articles-definis

**La Petite Fadette**, George Sand

> Sylvinet n’avait pas quitté son frère, et,
> quoiqu’il ne l’approuvât point d’avoir soulevé
> cette querelle, il se tenait tout prêt à le soutenir. Il
> y avait là quatre ou cinq grands jeunes gens qui
> avaient **la tête de plus que** les bessons ; mais,
> quand ils virent si résolus et comme, au fond, se
> battre pour si peu était à considérer, ils ne
> soufflèrent mot et se regardèrent les uns les
> autres, comme pour se demander lequel avait eu
> l’intention de se mesurer avec Landry.

Le sens de « tête » dans ce passage est visiblement le suivant, qui est extrait du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/t%C3%AAte).

> b) Hauteur d'une tête humaine, d'une tête animale utilisée comme unité de mesure. Dépasser qqn d'une tête; gagner d'une tête; avoir une tête de plus que qqn. Sa taille [d'Hercule] (...) s'était accrue d'une demi-tête (Proudhon, Guerre et paix, 1861, p. 16).

Il me semble que l'usage de l'article défini n'existe pas et qu'il n'est pas possible dans le français moderne lorsqu'on utilise « tête » dans ce sens. Est-ce exact ?

Comment: Le texte a été écrit il y a plusieurs décennies : à l’époque il était plus difficile de faire une correction dans l’édition que maintenant et remplacer «la» par «une». Commencer à corriger ses fautes serait une atteinte au texte tel qu’il a été publié (et validé par son auteure).

Comment: @PtitXav Il faudrait être certain que c'est une faute pour dire cela, ce qui parait être votre cas. Une preuve que cette certitude est bien fondée constitue une réponse, que vous pouvez faire. Personnellement, je reconnais une faute mais seulement par rapport à la langue d'aujourd'hui, ce qui mène à une considération plus sérieuse, mais n'en est pas une.

Comment: Après analyse, peut-être que l’expression « le tète de plus» ne correspond pas à la taille mais à ce qu’il y a dans la tête (intelligence , maturité) qui serait plus grande que chez les jumeaux.

Comment: @PtitXav C'est une idée intéressante, mais on se bat plus avec la force qu'avec l'intelligence dans le contexte donné par le texte, et la tête en plus est aussi synonyme de force en plus ; il est donc plutôt difficile de pencher pour cette explication.

Comment: Et aussi l’expérience en plus (ce qui peut servir dans un combat)

Comment: @PtitXav Le bagarreur (et encore plus le sportif spécialisé) a évidemment un avantage sur le plan de l'expérience, que l'on peut assimiler à de l'intelligence, mais dans le texte il n'est pas question de bagarreurs avant cette partie-ci ; tout ce qu'on trouve c'est que les garçons étaient quatre ou cinq  et aussi qu'ils étaient grands (ce qui pourrait aussi dire plus âgés, d'où la possible compréhension de « la tête » en tant que « expérience », cependant je doute de cela).